# Google sign in issue with Gigya SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, crash, google-signin, gigya

For some reasons I am using `Gigya SDK` for login into my app. I have followed steps from [Gigya SDK iOS](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/iOS). I have also added `Google SignIn SDK` through pod in my project.

When I am running my project I am getting crash,

> *** -[GTMSessionFetcherService fetcherWithRequest:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x28021eca0

All was working fine before I have added `Google SignIn` framework through pod. It still works fine for Facebook.

I have made a plain demo project too and it works fine in it.

In My main project, If I delete the app and install a new one. It works fine till I login through `Gigya SDK` and after that it crashes everytime with the above Crash. Everything works fine in my main project when I login with `Facebook`, It's only with Google SignIn I am getting this crash.

Don't know what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was mistake from our end. The settings for app on Gigya panel was wrong, we had few apps registered there, so settings got messed up. We have changed the settings and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK available in cocoa pods is not an official Gigya release and is not provided by Gigya (and is also several years out of date). Please only download and use official Gigya SDKs from https://downloads.gigya.com

Comment: Yes, I have installed the SDK manually, But for sign in with Google,I have installed their SDK with Pods.

Comment: Make sure that you are running Gigya.init in the main thread after.